# Xamarin Forms Button OnClick

Tags: c#, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have a ContentPage.cs in my project, using Xamarin Forms as work environment, and I was just wondering if I could be able to add an OnClick for the button that is at the end of the code.

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DebuggerTestAndroidIOS
{
    public class VSParameters : ContentPage
    {
        public VSParameters ()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("0ADF80"),
                        Children = {

                            new Label { Text = PatientInformation.PatientName,
                                TextColor= Color.White,
                                FontSize = 25
                            } 
                        }
                    },

                    //Patient Information Stack Layout
                    new StackLayout{ Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, 
                        Children = {

                            //Patient Image, sex and date of birth
                            new StackLayout{Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, Padding = new Thickness (30, 0, 0, 0),
                                Children = {

                                    new Image {Source = "UserMale.png"},
                                    new Label {Text = "Sex: " + PatientInformation.Sex  , FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black},
                                    new Label{Text = "Date of Birth: " + (PatientInformation.DateOfBirth).ToString(), FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black}
                                }

                            },

                            //other patient information
                            new StackLayout{Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, 
                                Children = {
                                    new Label {Text = "ID: " + PatientInformation.PatientID, FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black},


                                    new Label{Text = "Room: " + PatientInformation.RoomNumber, FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black},
                                    new Label {Text = "Bed: " + PatientInformation.BedID, FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black},
                                    new Label{Text = "Primary Doctor: " + PatientInformation.PrimaryDoctor, FontSize = 15, TextColor= Color.Black}

                                }

                            }


                        }
                    },
                    new StackLayout {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Padding = new Thickness(30, 0, 0, 0),
                        Children = {

                            new StackLayout{Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, 
                                Children = {
                                new Label {Text ="Heart Rate", FontSize= 20, TextColor = Color.FromHex("D95D65"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                    new Label {Text ="Temperature", FontSize= 20, TextColor = Color.FromHex("08CD78"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                new Label {Text ="Respiration Rate", FontSize= 20, TextColor = Color.FromHex("08CD78"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand},
                                new Label {Text ="Blood Pressure: ", FontSize= 20, TextColor = Color.FromHex("D95D65"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                    new Label {Text ="Systolic", FontSize= 18, TextColor = Color.FromHex("D95D65")},
                                new Label {Text ="Diastolic", FontSize= 18, TextColor = Color.FromHex("D95D65")}
                                }
                            },

                            new StackLayout{Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, 
                                Children = {
                                    new Entry {TextColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(231, 231, 231), WidthRequest= 100},
                                    new Entry {TextColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(231, 231, 231), WidthRequest= 100},
                                    new Entry {TextColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(231, 231, 231), WidthRequest= 100},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                    new Label{Text=""},
                                    new Label{Text=""},

                                    new Entry {TextColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(231, 231, 231), WidthRequest= 100},
                                    new Entry {TextColor = Color.Black, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(231, 231, 231), WidthRequest= 100},


                                }
                            },

                        }
                    
                    },

                    new StackLayout{HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        Children = {

                            new Button{Text = "Add parameters"}


                        }

                    }
                }
            };
        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want inline you can do this:

```
new Button {
    Text = "Add parameters"
    Command = new Command(() => {
        //Fix world hunger here
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Short and sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I never understood adding the controls inline. Perhaps you can access them later although without a name it would seem like you have to access them by some index of the stack which seems like a bad idea. So I don't have an answer exactly but rather a suggestion that would not fit well in a comment.

```
 public MyPage: ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage()
        {
            var slayout = new StackLayout();
            var button = new Button();
            button.click += (o,s) => {someevent};
            slayout.children.add(button);
            this.Content= slayout;
        }
    }
```

Creating the controls then adding them to the layout then adding the layout as the content will allow you to access the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Defined your button before the start of `Content = new StackLayout....`:

```
var myButton = new Button
{
    Text = "Add parameters"
};
myButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I've been clcked");
};
```

Then you add it as a child of the `StackLayout`.

This code:

```
new StackLayout{
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   Children = {
     new Button{Text = "Add parameters"}
   }
}
```

Becomes:

```
new StackLayout{
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   Children = {
     myButton
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your comment